# React hook, Invalid hook call error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a project using react hooks but getting this error below.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

And this is the code below

```
const authRequest = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Error!')
  const [authRequestState, authRequestTrue] = React.useState(false)
  authRequestTrue(true)
}


const renderFormikForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{country: '', number: ''}} onSubmit={(values) => {submitForm(values)}}>
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur}) => (
        <form>
          <div className='input-box'>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='emial' value='libeto@commontown.co'/>
            </p>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='number' name='number' placeholder='number' value={values.number} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '50%'}} />
              <button onClick={(e) => authRequest(e)}><em><a>Click!!!</a></em></button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

So basically, functional component renders **renderFormikForm component** and when I click the button (say Click!!!) onClick triggers authRequest function but instead state is changed, it gives me the error that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks can only be created inside function components. You need to **use useState inside the function component**.

Update your code to following:

```
const renderFormikForm = () => {
  const [authRequestState, authRequestTrue] = React.useState(false)

  const authRequest = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Error!')
    authRequestTrue(true)
  }
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{country: '', number: ''}} onSubmit={(values) => {submitForm(values)}}>
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur}) => (
        <form>
          <div className='input-box'>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='emial' value='libeto@commontown.co'/>
            </p>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='number' name='number' placeholder='number' value={values.number} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '50%'}} />
              <button onClick={(e) => authRequest(e)}><em><a>Click!!!</a></em></button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

or you can also re-write it as follows:

```
const authRequest = (e: any, authRequestTrue) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Error!')
  authRequestTrue(true)
}
const renderFormikForm = () => {
  const [authRequestState, authRequestTrue] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{country: '', number: ''}} onSubmit={(values) => {submitForm(values)}}>
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur}) => (
        <form>
          <div className='input-box'>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='emial' value='libeto@commontown.co'/>
            </p>
            <p className='input'>
              <input type='number' name='number' placeholder='number' value={values.number} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '50%'}} />
              <button onClick={(e) => authRequest(e, authRequestTrue)}><em><a>Click!!!</a></em></button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

The latter one is more closer to the code mentioned in question.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.